# Cannot insert the value NULL into column

Tags: sql, null, sql-update

I'm having some problems. I am trying to get a table to update, however it is not updating because one of the fields contains rows with a NULL value.

Heres the original query which gives no error:

```
        sql="UPDATE empPac SET quantityLimit = allocation, allocationStart = '"&allocationStart&"', nextUpdate = DATEADD(mm, allocationMonths, "&allocationStart&"), lastUpdate = GETDATE(), quantityIssued = 0, quantityShipped = 0 WHERE allocationMonths <> 0 AND nextUpdate <= DATEADD(mm, "&checkCondition&", GETDATE()) and empIdent in (select empIdent from employee where custIdent='"&custIdent&"')"
```

Now, the nextUpdate column might be NULL, so I am trying to accommodate for that with this query:

```
        sql="UPDATE empPac SET quantityLimit = allocation, allocationStart = '"&allocationStart&"', nextUpdate = DATEADD(mm, allocationMonths, "&allocationStart&"), lastUpdate = GETDATE(), quantityIssued = 0, quantityShipped = 0 WHERE allocationMonths <> 0 AND (nextUpdate <= DATEADD(mm, "&checkCondition&", GETDATE()) OR nextUpdate IS NULL) and empIdent in (select empIdent from employee where custIdent='"&custIdent&"')"
```

You can see I've added "OR nextUpdate IS NULL" in brackets with the other condition for nextUpdate.

However, I am getting an error "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'quantityLimit', table 'myname.dbo.EmpPac'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails."

This makes no sense to me as, when viewing myLittleAdmin, shows me a NULL value for some rows in that table column.

Comment: You should really parametrize your queries http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `OR nextUpdate IS NULL` to your `WHERE` clause **widens** the search criteria - i.e. more rows can be found.

Apparently, one of these additional rows has a NULL in `allocation` field (which then  gets assigned to `quantityLimit` which, according to the error message, is NOT NULL).

Comment: awesome, I added "WHERE allocation IS NOT NULL" and it works now :) thank you all

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with the NextUpdate column being NULL, this has to do with the allocation column in empPac table being NULL. Handle the allocation column being NULL (or fix the data) and it will work fine.

EDIT: The only thing I can guarantee with this is that the error will go away:

```
sql="UPDATE empPac SET quantityLimit = allocation, allocationStart = '"&allocationStart&"', nextUpdate = DATEADD(mm, allocationMonths, "&allocationStart&"), lastUpdate = GETDATE(), quantityIssued = 0, quantityShipped = 0 WHERE allocationMonths <> 0 AND (nextUpdate <= DATEADD(mm, "&checkCondition&", GETDATE()) OR nextUpdate IS NULL) and empIdent in (select empIdent from employee where custIdent='"&custIdent&"') AND allocation IS NOT NULL"
```

Comment: So you have nowhere in your empPac table where allocation is NULL? If you do, then your WHERE clause is causing rows with a NULL allocation to be selected for the update. Again, figure out where the allocation column is NULL (by running your update as a SELECT with some additional columns to help identify the rows) and handle that parameter or fix the data.

Comment: Edit: See my fix. It won't guarantee that quantityLimit will be updated correctly but it will stop the error.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not the column `nextUpdate`; according to the error message, the problem is an attempt to assign `NULL` into the column `quantityLimit`. Looking at your code, you are setting `quantityLimit` equal to the value `allocation`, which I presume is another column in your database - make sure that column or input is not null.

Comment: the first query works fine though. the problem occurs when i add to the WHERE...see the first query in my OP, that gives no errors...the second query i posted in the OP does though. this is why im lost.

Answer (score 0):

Just an Observation, if you try to Edit a table column to make it Not Null which were null previously . You may get an error saying:

> "cannot insert the value null into column update fails"

Even though you got the correct update sql statement in place

```
ALTER TABLE
[dbo].[Table name] 
ALTER COLUMN
  [Column Name]
    NVARCHAR(250) NOT NULL;
```

Solution: Very simple

1. Insert some value on the empty rows of the same column
2. Try to execute update statement now .
   Hope this save some time and would helps.

Vinu Nair